# How to do a bitwise AND on integers in VHDL?

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I'm learning VHDL and I'm having a problem with some code I'm trying to write to satisfy a bound-check exception.

Here is my basic summarized code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 
...
port(
Address: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
...
constant SIZE : integer := 4096;
variable addr: integer range 0 to SIZE-1 := 0;
...
process ... 
addr := conv_integer(Address) and (SIZE-1); --error here
```

The error message I get is

> src/memory.vhd:37:35: no function declarations for operator "and"

Basically, my goal is to make a 16-bit address bus, reference memory with only 4096 bytes. Why do I get this odd error? Am I missing a library include or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Don't use `std_logic_arith` *and* `numeric_std`. And [you don't need `std_logic_arith`](http://parallelpoints.com/node/3)

You can't do bitwise ANDs on integers, so you need to do something like:

```
addr := Address and to_unsigned(SIZE-1, Address'length);
```

But you'll probably want to guarantee SIZE is a power-of-2

what I tend to do is create a constant in *bits* and work up from there:

```
constant mem_bits : integer := 16;
constant SIZE     : integer := 2**16;
```

then

```
addr := Address(mem_bits-1 downto 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `and` is defined for integers, although there might be a standard library that includes that functionality.

Why not keep your address as a `std_logic_vector` though? When it comes to addresses, you often want to be able to do easy decoding by looking directly at certain bits, so I think it makes rather good sense.

Just make `addr` a `std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)`, and assign the lowest 12 bits of `address` to it - that will ignore the upper 4 bytes, and give you 4096 bytes of space (for an 8-bit databus).

Comment: Is it possible to specify a "dynamic" range then based on SIZE ? I want to in the future be able to change SIZE and not have to make any other modifications

Comment: Also, be careful of variables. They might look nice and C-like, but you won't necessarily know what they actually implement as. I usually stick to signals or combinatorial logic outside a `process`, unless I really really have to use a variable. I guess it's a question of style though.

Comment: Have a look at `generic` (or package-defined constants) for defining the size of your `addr` vector. That should help you make it configurable.

Comment: I have an example from some of my own code here btw: http://opencores.org/websvn,filedetails?repname=tosnet&path=%2Ftosnet%2Ftrunk%2Fgateware%2FTosNet_rev3_2%2Flfsr.vhd - although I probably should just have used `integer` directly for the generic types...

Comment: Don't be afraid of variables - you *can * tell what you get from variables in a clocked process: If you only refer to them after they are written to, you get combinational logic.  If you refer to them before, you get flipflops with combinational logic feeding them.  You can also do both and the synthesiser will figure out what side of the flipflop you want in order to match the function you describe

Answer (score 2):

And does not make sense for an integer.  Integer is a number within a range, but it has no standard way of implementing itself, i.e. it has no predefined representation in binary.

you can use something like the syntax, below;

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;





entity testand is
    generic (nBITS:integer:=32);
    port (
        i:in integer;
        a:in std_logic_vector(nBITS-1 downto 0);
        o:out std_logic_vector(nBITS-1 downto 0));
end entity;



architecture beh of testand is

signal v:std_logic_vector(a'length-1 downto 0);

begin

    v<=std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(i,o'length));

    o<=v and a;


end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you could also use "mod SIZE" instead of "and (SIZE-1)".